# What to do when a classification problem doesn't seem possible?

Tags: classification, predictive-models

I'm working on a binary classification problem using 10 predictors.  I have 4508 data points.  I am required to have a prediction scheme which achieves an accuracy of 80% or better.  However I am discouraged by the appearance of my data.  It seems like the classification problem is not possible with what I have been given.  Here are two group/scatter plots over two pairs of predictors.  (It's same over all pairs.)

[image: Predictors 2 and 10][image: Predictors 2 and 3]

What do you recommend?

Update:  Here is a non-linear embedding of a subset of the data into 2 dimensions.  Red colours are class one and blue colours are class zero.  (Sorry for the picture size)

[image: Diffusion Map]

And another one using another method:  [image: t-SNE]

Comment: It might be well separated in the original feature space $R^{10}$. If you do want to visualize the data in low-dimensional space, it is suggestive to use the first few principal components.

Comment: One of the great things about machine learning algorithms is that they can find patterns that we humans have trouble seeing. @Zhanxiong's idea is a good way to look at the data, but you can also try some algorithms and see what you get. I guess the answer to your question is not to get discouraged until you've tried a lot of things.

Answer (score 2):

Not everything can be predicted, if this were the case I'd stick a random forest on the stock market and retire :)

Might I suggest you try feature engineering? For example, if you have names like Mrs Jones, Mr Smith, Miss Johnson... try using delimiters to create a new variable for the title of their names, then rerun the models.